# if user is on a specific page and a div exisits then do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to check if I'm on a specific page  and if I'm  inside that page and a div exists to do something.

I know how to check if a specific page exists: `if('http://'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'/stats')`

I know to check if a specific div exists: `if($(".div").length) {`

but how can I add the second if inside the first if ?

I've tried this but is not working:

```
if('http://'+location.hostname+location.pathname+'/stats') {
   if($(".div").length) { //do something;}
}
```

Is this possible with jQuery ?

Comment: Load contents of this page via `$.load` (if it's not on the same domain - try JSONP or something else)

Comment: you need to parse that page, the way you are doing you're trying to find ".div" in your current page

Comment: That's *not* how you check if a specific page exists. You could use `if("my-great-page-that-is-made-up")` and it would evaluate as `true`. The problem isn't with the syntax if your nested `if` statements, it's that your outer `if` statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: Learn about Ajax or iframes...

Comment: @meagar, can you please give me an example on how can you do it ?

Comment: I do not understand why you are telling me to use ajax, I just want to check if I'm on specific URL and if I'm on that URL and a div exists to hide it ? Again why do I need to use AJAX for this ?

Comment: and why are you suggesting that this answer already exists on another page because I don't see any similarity with my question ?

Comment: @Alecs If that is the case then you worded the question very badly. You might consider refactoring it to highlight *that* requirement

Comment: @RGraham, I've modified my question, sorry, my bad, I said if a page exists not **if I'm on a specific page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just testing that a string exists here (which will always evaluate to true), not that the current URL is equal to what you expect.

```
if(location.pathname === "/stats" && $(".div").length) {
    // Do Something
}
```

You need to use the equals parameter to compare against pathname as above.

Comment: I've just tried it in console and I'm getting : `Undefined` and nothing happens...

Comment: Then there is an error in your code somewhere. Have a look at this fiddle for an example - http://jsfiddle.net/7j5AH/

Comment: Oh yes, It was my code. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax call and in the success call back you could check if that div element exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery.load to load your page and get the content of specific element like the following:

```
 $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Here, jQuery will load the `test.html` page and internally will parse and then return the content of element which has id `container`.

You can see the complete reference in [jQuery Load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

You will **not** be able to achieve what you want (unless all pages of interest are in the same domain) without some server-side support of any kind. Browsers will prevent you from gathering content that lives in another domain using AJAX because of the [Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

However the solution is quite simple: implement a server-side service that performs that task and consume it from the client application. If you can't, you may use an online service such as [YQL](http://www.markandey.com/2010/10/yql-page-scraping-yes-anyone-can-do-it.html) instead of implementing your own.

Please also note that `if ('http://www.some-url-in-string.com')` doesn't do what you expect. A string doesn't inherit any features based on it's content (*1. almost true*). I could create a string such as `'the-most-important-string-of-all-times'` and it won't be treated differently by the JS engine.

*1. Empty strings are falsey while all other strings are truthy.*

```
!!''; //false
!!'anything'; //true
```